# Should I involve the dependent variable when imputing missing values for an independent variable?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, data-imputation

I am building a model for predicting whether my users would recommend my wine. In the final model, the dependent variable, $Y_{ni}$ is whether user $n$ recommends wine variant $i$. However, in some cases, the income level of $n$, $Z_n$, is missing, and NOT at random (that is, a larger proportion of younger users have missing income level).

Now I really like the income variable, and do not want to exclude it in my final model. Therefore, I set out to impute this categorical variable $Z_n$ for where it is missing, using a simple multinomial logit model. My question is, should I involve $Y_{ni}$ in the imputation of $Z_n$? Why or why not, what is the best way to think about this? Does the answer depend on the final model family where $Y_{ni}$ is the dependent variable?

Comment: Paul Allison, in his 2001 book *Missing Data*, clearly states that using the DV when imputing missing information for predictors is not only viable, it's recommended.

Comment: @MikeHunter Does that not create problems with overfitting?

Comment: @MikeHunter Thanks for the reference! Do you have a quick intuition as to why this was recommended?